# PL/SQL function returning no value

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am getting a ORA-06503 error which is "Function returned without value". I wanted to know whether this error occurs when query inside function finds a NULL value and the function is trying to return the NULL value retrieved ?
Here is the function outline -

```
FUNCTION getEmailAddress (user IN VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
v_email             xxxxTable.email%TYPE;
BEGIN
 SELECT email
 INTO   v_email
 FROM   xxxxTable
 WHERE  user_id = user;
 RETURN v_email;
EXCEPTION
 WHEN OTHERS
 THEN
  RETURN constantValue;
END getEmailAddress;
```

Any clarification here would be helpful

Thanks

Comment: What's this constantValue? Anyway, It looks like you're trying to trap a "no rows returned" error -- do so specifically with "Exception When NO_DATA_FOUND ...". Re-run it and see if you're getting any other errors.

Comment: constantValue is a default email address.

Comment: This is not the complete code, is it?

Comment: I'm not sure that user is a good name for a variable either. It's an Oracle reserved word.

Comment: this function is part of a trigger. So this is all the function code i have and I have changed the variable names here .. like its actually not "user" it has a valid variable name.

Comment: The problem with that approach there is that you may have edited out the cause of the problem, or introduced new ones that make it impossible to reproduce your result. Better to post the original.

Answer (score 3):

Returning a null still counts as returning a value. However selecting no rows raises an error. Possibly you are trapping it with an EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS clause, which is a bad habit to get into.

Answer (score 2):

It means your function is not returning anything at all - not `null`, but there's some branch that exits without calling `return` at all.

A likely culprit is an `exception` block which catches something - quite possibly `when others` - and then doesn't (re)raise and doesn't itself `return`. A `return` between the `begin` and `exception` would be skipped if an exception was actually raised.

Speculating, of course; showing the function code in the question would clarify the issue.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora06503.php) "You tried to call a PLSQL function, but the function was **missing a RETURN statement**."

Proposed solution:
"Try re-writing the function to include a RETURN statement. Or if you don't want to return a value, re-write your function as a procedure."

This error is **not** raised because the return value was `NULL`.

Posting some of your code would help us spot the exact problem more easily (instead of taking our best guess on this).